# Core Data rearranging instances randomly

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I am building a weather app that uses core data to store locations ('spaces' in my app). Everything is working fine besides one thing. When I select one of my locations (to change the city being displayed on the home page), core data rearranges the order of my fetched results. It doesn't happen every time, but most of the time it does and I'm not sure why. Below are screenshots of my app and snippets of my code. I can provide more of my code if this is not enough to solve or understand the problem. Thanks in advance!

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Home Page

```
import SwiftUI

struct Home: View {
    @State private var showingAddSpace = false
    @State private var showingSpaces = false
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var spaces: FetchedResults<CachedSpace>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button {
                    showingSpaces.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                        .font(.title2)
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button {
                    showingAddSpace.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .font(.title2)
                }
            }
            
            Text(spaces.count == 0 ? "San Jose" : spaces[CachedSpace.activeIndex].wrappedCity)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddSpace) {
            AddSpace()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingSpaces) {
            Spaces()
        }
    }
}

struct Home_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Home()
    }
}
```

Locations Display Page

```
import SwiftUI

struct Spaces: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var spaces: FetchedResults<CachedSpace>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(spaces) { space in
                    HStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text(space.wrappedCity)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                            Text("\(space.wrappedTemperature)°")
                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if let index = spaces.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == space.id}) {
                                let index = index
                                CachedSpace.activeIndex = index
                                print(CachedSpace.activeIndex)
                                print(spaces[CachedSpace.activeIndex].wrappedCity)
                            }
                            
                            for s in spaces {
                                s.active = false
                            }
                            
                            space.active.toggle()
                            dismiss()
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button {
                            print(space)
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: space.active == true ? "star.fill" : "star")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteSpace)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Desmond's Spaces")
        }
    }
    
    func deleteSpace(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for offset in offsets {
            let space = spaces[offset]
            moc.delete(space)
        }

        try? moc.save()
    }
}

struct Spaces_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Spaces()
    }
}
```

Core Data Properties

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension CachedSpace {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CachedSpace> {
        return NSFetchRequest<CachedSpace>(entityName: "CachedSpace")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var city: String?
    @NSManaged public var temperature: String?
    @NSManaged public var active: Bool
    
    var wrappedCity: String {
        city ?? ""
    }
    
    var wrappedTemperature: String {
        temperature ?? ""
    }
    
    static var activeIndex = 0

}

extension CachedSpace : Identifiable {

}
```

Page to Add Locations

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddSpace: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var spaces: FetchedResults<CachedSpace>
    
    @State private var city = ""
    @State private var temperature = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                TextField("City", text: $city)
                TextField("Temperature", text: $temperature)
                Button("Save") {
                    let newSpace = CachedSpace(context: moc)
                    
                    newSpace.city = city
                    newSpace.temperature = temperature
                    newSpace.active = false
                    newSpace.id = UUID()
                    
                    try? moc.save()
                    
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AddSpace_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddSpace()
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no guaranteed order for which objects are returned from a fetch request, if you want a specific order then you need to supply sort descriptors. Something like `NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \CachedSpace.name, ascending: true)`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson do sort descriptors sort the actual data or just how it's viewed? My app is dependent on using the indices. Also, is there a descriptor to sort by newest/oldest?

Comment: It's sort the actual data based on the attribute you supply. You should read up on NSSortDescriptor if you want to work with Core Data.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson When you have the answer to a question it would be better to post it as an answer instead of as a comment. When you post as a comment, the question continues to look as if it’s unanswered, even though you have already provided an answer.

Comment: @TomHarrington I was to lazy to find a duplicate, fixed that now